# Require password when quitting application

Tags: security, password, menu-bar

I am setting up computers to run at a visitor centre, to be used by the public. I have been able to work out how to use Google Chrome in kiosk mode, but not a way for people to not be able to easily exit the application.

Is it possible to set up my Macs (running El Capitan, 10.11.6) to **require a password to successfully exit an app**? I am perfectly fine with a programming solution, but will need guidance in what to change, to what, and what the change implies. I can also settle for a solution specific for an Internet reader, but having something more general for an app would be preferable. A free method would be preferable, but we are open for considering paid options as well (we are considering eCrisper, but would like to explore other alternatives).

Comment: Please advise, if a free or paid method is required and if there is a max budget (under $10). Also, if you are looking just for an internet kiosk solution, is closing the net app the only thing that ultimately matters and are you comfortable with editing a .plist file? I have a few solutions but want to stick to your preferred need.

Comment: @norcaljohnny I have now updated the question, specifying that I would be most happy with a free solution, but can consider a paid alternative ifmustbe. I am very happy to edit .plist files, but have no experience in doing so.

Comment: please forgive me. In regards to a web browser solution, will a guest user have access across the internet, a specific page or pages?

Comment: @norcaljohnny They will be accessing one webpage, but should be able to navigate across the webpage. Potentially a few number of pages, and their relatives, to put it that way.